# Scheduling a task to run at the end of every month. (Windows Server 2003 - Scheduled Tasks)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task to run on the last night of each month, on a Windows 2003 Server.

I see that you can schedule it to run on the "first or last Mon-Fri", or even on the nth day of each month - but, not how to get it to run on the last day (regardless of day of the week or number).

Thanks in advance.

Note: I did check "[How do you schedule tasks in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429/how-do-you-schedule-tasks-in-windows)", etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have to set up multiple schedules for your task. One schedule for the months with 31 days, another for those with 30, and one more for February. See this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936627

Comment: Or if the requirements are not too picky, it's easier to schedule the job for every 1st or 28th day...

Comment: +1 Thanks - That's what I was looking for.  @ewall Yeah, way too picky I'm afraid. :) But that would have generated some really funny results for my app.

Answer (score 5):

I do it a little differently - I run one task every day but since the task is in vbscript - I do this:

```
DIM datecur, datefut


datecur = DATEPART("m",NOW())
datefut = DATEPART("m",NOW()+1)

If (datecur <> datefut) then
'insert code you want to run here
end if
```

Simple and it works - hope this helps someone

Comment: In English: if Tomorrow is in Next Month then do the action.

Comment: Another business logic approach I have come across, using calendar functions; 

    If today = ( Day 1 of Next Month ) - 1
    Then today is end of Month.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2022, much newer Windows version (2019)
I see this option in Triggers:

WinScheduler Task Triggers
Begin the task: On a schedule
Settings:

> Monthly
> On:  Last > then select All weekdays